# I did git rebase to solve an error but when i am doing git branch getting (no branch , rebasing <branch>) and also all the code in my editor changed

Tags: git, github

Hello I am using github tool as i am a new guy in this technology and every time when i was trying to push the changes from any of the branch to the master branch i was getting error that pushing rejected some kind of error so i watched on youtube and there i seen a command git pull --rebase and i did it now my local project changed all the changes are not showing and i am facing difficulty in solving this issue. Please help???

[this is the error i am getting now when i trying to see on which branch i am now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NEUN.png)

[And this is what i am getting now i think the work i have done is save in loginAndRegister branch but i am somehow not able to merge everything together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvdps.png)

Please help :)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You started a rebase without having a clear idea of what the rebase was supposed to accomplish, then you ran into a conflict. `git rebase --abort` should fix your repo.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently in the middle of a rebase, because you have a conflict on file `product-detail.js`. Normally when you have conflicts, you resolve them in the tool of your choice, stage the updated file, and then continue the rebase:

```
git rebase --continue
```

If you are unhappy with the rebase and wish to cancel it and go back to where you were before:

```
git rebase --abort
```

The error you got when you pushed, presumably was that your branch had diverged. To integrate the remote changes, you need to either merge (the default) or rebase (like you specified with `git pull --rebase`). Most likely you would have had conflicts either way, and you'll probably need to resolve them to continue.

**Tip:** I've seen people who have just started learning Git, when seeing conflicts, throw up their hands in disgust and start over. Then they make a new branch from the latest version of the remote branch, and then they manually copy their work back in so they can make a new commit. At some point while doing this they attempt to copy their line into the file that had a conflict, and that's when they realize they still have to figure out how to resolve it. Initially it may be easier to resolve it outside of Git without the merge conflict symbols integrated into the file, but once you get the hang of it, the way Git presents conflicts is actually pretty helpful (especially compared to doing it manually).